# Clarification on Lemma problem

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

I have trouble understanding this question. I have no idea where to start.

Let $A$ be the set of palindromes over $\{a, b\}$.

Suppose you are trying to prove that $A$ is not regular using the pumping lemma. Your
proof starts (correctly) like this:
Suppose for a contradiction that $A$ is regular. Let $p$ be the pumping length given by the
pumping lemma.
Now you have to choose string $s$. For each choice of $s$ below, you have to state whether
or not this choice of $s$ can be used to finish the proof that $A$ is not regular.

> (a) $s=b^pa^pb^p$. Can this $s$ be used? Briefly explain your answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can. Assume we can write $s=uvw$ with  $|uv|\le p$ and $v$ nonempty. Then $uv$ is just a sequnce of $b$'s. By the pumping lemma we should have $uw\in A$, but $uw=b^xa^pb^p$ with $x=p-|v|<p$ is ("obviously") not a palindrome.